# RichTextbox, FlowDocument unable to left align

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a `RichTextBox` and a `FlowDocument` like so in my ResourceDictionary (no-code behind), and my original window loads with a relatively wider size.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="2">
    <FlowDocument Name="Msg" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
      <FlowDocument.Tag>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConv}">
             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
             <Binding Path="Speed"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </FlowDocument.Tag>
    </FlowDocument>
  </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
  <Button Content="Button" Margin="1,0,4,0" MinWidth="25" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Here we can see that the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`'s default size/border extends till the full (grid) width irrespective of its inner content, and because of which the Button goes out of visual scope.
I also tried `RichTextbox` instead of `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` but its the same problem.

As a work-around I can do `Margin='-20,0,0,0'` on the `Button` but that's not a good idea as that will force the button over the text when window is made much smaller.
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Although it seems obvious, this is a good example of a question that could do with an image, annotate it with the desired behaviour

Comment: @ChrisSchaller: Can you elaborate ! Thanks

Comment: Please upload a screenshot that shows the current output, draw over the top of it to highlight what you want to change, include a second screenshot that shows your workaround.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller: Updated question with image. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe: Can you fix the _XAML_ above to include  `<DockPanel>` tag and `</Grid>` tag too, please?

Comment: @Joe: Look at the following post: [WPF - Auto width for FlowDocument's content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22612/wpf-auto-width-for-flowdocuments-content.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at that.